# In Canvas drawing,how move ShapeDrawble object that created by path?

Tags: android

In Canvas drawing,how move ShapeDrawble object that created by path will effecient?

The code below is seemingly through new path to move,so that hava to recreate ShapeDrawable object every time.This is very waste resources,is there any way to solve?

```
private void drawBitmapShape(Canvas canvas, Paint paint)
    {
         /*Draw a hollow triangle*/
        Path path=new Path();
        path.moveTo(10, 330);
        path.lineTo(70,330);
        path.lineTo(40,270);
        path.close();
        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        /* create ShapeDrawable object and define the shape is elliptic */
        mShape = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, BitQQheight, BitQQheight));

        /* set up the ellipse things to draw for ShapeDrawable pictures */
        mShape.getPaint().setShader(mBitmapShader);
        /*set display area*/
        //BitQQheight=BitQQheight*2;
        mShape.setBounds(0,0, BitQQwidth, BitQQheight);

        /* draw ShapeDrawableQQ */
        mShape.draw(canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solve it

```
private void drawBitmapShape(Canvas canvas, Paint paint)
    {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(5, 5);
        // rotate
        //canvas.rotate(90, 60, 310);
         /*Draw a hollow triangle*/
        Path path=new Path();
        path.moveTo(10, 330);
        path.lineTo(70,330);
        path.lineTo(40,270);
        path.close();
        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        /* create ShapeDrawable object and define the shape is elliptic */
        mShape = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, BitQQheight, BitQQheight));

        /* set up the ellipse things to draw for ShapeDrawable pictures */
        mShape.getPaint().setShader(mBitmapShader);
        /* set display area */
        //BitQQheight=BitQQheight*2;
        mShape.setBounds(0,0, BitQQwidth, BitQQheight);

        /* draw ShapeDrawableQQ */
        mShape.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```